# Colorbar axis ticks changing color on 3D figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've been trying to change the ticks on the colorbar axis on my 3D but I've encountered the problem where if I do so the color on the entire 3D figure changes. Basically what I'm trying to do is maintain the same kind of color range on the 3D figure while changing the color bar values from 0 - 80 to 50 - 450 instead without changing the color on the actual figure.

Thanks in advance!

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

filename = ['*File pathway to the datafiles*' 'filenames.txt'];
T = readtable(filename);
tsize = size(T);
tsize (1);

filename = strcat('*File pathway to the datafiles*', string(T{1,1}));
heat = double(getHeatMap(filename));

%load('myMap2.mat');
figure
set(gcf,'Visible','on')
for i = 1:tsize
    filename = strcat('*File pathway to the datafiles*', string(T{i,1}));
    if dir(filename).bytes == 0
        continue;
    end
    heat = double(getHeatMap(filename));
    [X,tY] = meshgrid( linspace(1,400,size(heat,2)),linspace(0,2*pi,size(heat,1)));
    max_heat = max(heat, [], 'all');
    min_heat = min(heat, [], 'all');
    R = (((heat-min_heat)/(max_heat-min_heat))*50)+100;
    Y = cos(tY) .* R;
    Z = sin(tY) .* R;
    [nx, ny, nz] = surfnorm(X,Y,Z);
    nv = reshape([nx ny nz], size(nx,1),size(nx,2),3);
    CV = R;
    s = surf(X,Y,Z,heat,'VertexNormals',nv, 'EdgeColor','none');
    axis([0 400 -200 200 -200 200])
    colorbar
    colormap('parula')
    lighting gouraud
    camlight
    material dull
    caxis([0 80])
    drawnow
end
function heat = getHeatMap(filename)
s = dir(filename);
fin=fopen(filename,'r');
I=fread(fin,s.bytes,'uint8=>uint8');
w = uint16(I(1))+256*uint16(I(2));
h = uint16(I(3))+256*uint16(I(4));
skip = s.bytes - w*h + 1;
IN = I(skip:1:s.bytes);
Z=single(reshape(IN,w,h));
Z=griddedInterpolant(Z');
y_range = linspace(1.0,single(h),256);
x_range = linspace(1.0,single(w),512);
heat = uint8(Z({y_range, x_range}));
end
```

[Pastebin link to the datafile, should be saved as 0000.OTT so it can be run.](https://pastebin.com/tikgzrds)

Before colorbar axis change

[image]

After changing colorbar axis between the range 50 - 450 using caxis([50 450])
[image]

Comment: The color of the surface is given by you, as the input `heat` to surf. It feels like the easy thing here is simply changing that input, no? If you just do `surf(X,Y,Z, heat*400/80+50 ,....` you should get what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I had been looking at the wrong place the whole time. btw I have I another question, I get the error message: "Error using  : 
Colon operands must be in the range of the data type.
Error in RotaryKiln3D>getHeatMap (line 51)
IN = I(skip:1:s.bytes);".
When using this dataset, Pastebin-link: https://pastebin.com/UhSBEDjt

Comment: Just do `IN = I(double(skip):1:double(s.bytes));` I believe. I think it has to do with the data types of those variables

Comment: I instead get issues on the next line after it, do I have to change their values to doubles as well?

Error message: "Error using reshape
Number of elements must not change. Use [] as one of the size inputs to automatically calculate the appropriate size for that dimension.
Error in RotaryKiln3D>getHeatMap (line 54)
Z=single(reshape(IN,w,h));"

Comment: Read the error message, check the values of your numbers. Do they make sense? Why not? is the error message unclear? how?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't understand what the problem is. I've tried troubleshooting but I've come up with no solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238537/discussion-between-codexing-and-ander-biguri).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the surface is given by you, as the input heat to surf. It feels like the easy thing here is simply changing that input.

If you just do `surf(X,Y,Z, heat*400/80+50 ,....` you should get what you want.